# Kerberos: ok-as-delegate missing from ticket on OS X

Tags: macos, kerberos

I work as a React Developer for a company that chose to use IIS and SQL as their backend. The API calls don't use JWT but rather use Kerberos tickets.

This already presents an issue that I have to run chrome with --auth-server-whitelist="*" in order to get a ticket from kerberos at all. However, I am still unable to make API calls.

The best we can tell is my kerberos ticket (which can be viewed by issuing *klist* to terminal. The only difference between one that works on a PC and mine is that theirs has the ok-as-delegate flag and mine does not.

Surely there is a configuration issue on the backend or with IIS preventing my ticket from attaining this flag? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is JWT?  Never heard of it...

Comment: Do you get a Service Ticket (check your `klist` output for tickets matching the server name)?

Comment: @sborsky I did get a TGT from the appropriate server.

Comment: @john JWT is JSON web token and it’s what we should’ve been using for making api calls with a react front end.

Comment: You'll also need a Service Ticket. Chrome should request that from the KDC (AD) using your TGT. `klist` should show it as `HTTP/<your-server-name-or-fqdn>` (that is the Service Principal Name - SPN). If not, your HTTP URL (the servername part) might not match the IIS' SPN.

Comment: @sborsky yes I do have that ticket, the problem is that with that particular ticket there is no ok-as-delegate flag, so the API calls aren't receiving my credentials on the backend (so I'm told) the PC users here have the same ticket as me but with the flag I just mentioned. Indicating to me that the issue is simply that I don't have the ok-as-delegate flag. The question is whether that's a Mac client config issue or a server config issue

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood - what do you mean by "The only difference between one that works on a PC and mine is that theirs has the ok-as-delegate flag and mine does not."  Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the "ok-as-delegate flag" from a *good* ticket?  By "ok-as-delegate flag", do you mean "proxiable"?

Comment: Heron, I will update when I’m not in the middle of moving. But no, the exact ticket flag is okay-as-delegate on the windows ticket. Seen using klist it’s not a very common flag.

Comment: I've done some research on this.  It appears that some GSSAPI implementations (such as various UNIX flavors, and in your case, the Mac), do not honor the okay-as-delegate" on the Windows ticket, and thus that flag is not shown.  See:  https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/apm-sso-kerberos-double-hop-delegation-issue-47932